# Python pandas losing columns when concat two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concat two data frames.They have different column numbers, one has 5, one has 6. After I concatenate them, the columns are all there.

```
df1
    Project_ID   Use       Sector Total_Amount
    C123456      Other     B      789
    C678903      Business  A      901
df2
    Project_ID   Use       Sector  Sub-sector   Total_Amount
    C123456      Other     B        C           789
    C678903      Business  A        D           901
new_df = concat([df1,df2],sort=False)
new_df

   Project_ID     Use      Sector     Subsector     Total Amount
   C123456        Other    B          NaN           789
   C123456        Other    B          C             789
   C678903        Business A          NaN           901
   C678903        Business A          D             901
```

However, when I tried to add a new column to `new_df`,it gives me key error:

```
new_df["dummy"] = new_df.groupby(['Project_ID']).cumcount()+1
KeyError: 'Project ID'
```

When I re-print`new_df`, I found indeed Project_ID column went missing. This is very weird based on my experience. Would really appreciate it if someone can tell me where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate your error.

Two things though. In your code exmaple I believe `concat([df1, df2]....` should be `pd.concat(....`

Also, the following should work. It seems that your reported error is different from what you typed. Maybe check your spelling and try again.

```
new_df["dummy"] = new_df.groupby(['Project_ID']).cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and it worked.  Here's what I entered.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Project_ID': ['C123456', 'C678903'],
    'Use': ['Other', 'Business'],
    'Sector': ['B', 'A'],
    'Total_Amount': [789, 901],
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Project_ID': ['C123456', 'C678903'],
    'Use': ['Other', 'Business'],
    'Sector': ['B', 'A'],
    'Sub-sector': ['C', 'D'],
    'Total_Amount': [789, 901],
})
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
new_df["dummy"] = new_df.groupby('Project_ID').cumcount() + 1
```

```py
new_df
Out[3]: 
  Project_ID  ... dummy
0    C123456  ...     1
1    C678903  ...     1
0    C123456  ...     2
1    C678903  ...     2
[4 rows x 6 columns]
```